# My project get disturbed oftenly when i get latest version in tfs 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, azure-devops

I am newbie in TFS 2010. 
I have installed TFS 2010 on server and successfully connected.
I am doing check in for comitting my changed file and get latest version from other computer. Most of the time it works fine but oftenly js or style file gets corrupt.
Suppose i have two systems connected to TFS on server.

**System A**
1- I do change in abc.aspx.
2- I check in.
3- I keep on working on system and edit 4 files.
4- I check in.

**System B**
1- I get latest version.
2- I get abc.aspx changed.
3- I am doing work on some other files.
4- I get latest version, from System A i receive change in 3 files where as 4th file remain same.

Some times the project gets corrupt in a way the design gets bad and aspx page disturbs.

I tried to find help on websites but there is not much tfs help available. Please guide me where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to clean client and server caches. See http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/07/06/Clear-the-cache-of-TFS.aspx